# How to force bad checksum on packet using scapy PcapWriter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy, packet

I'm using scapy for automated changing of packet fields (mixing pcaps). In case of packets with bad checksum i need to avoid scapy automatically calculating the correct checksum. 
This is done automatically when writing new packets into pcap using the PcapWriter. Is there a way to prevent it from recalculating checksum on packets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scapy only fills checksum if the previous one was set to `None`.
If you manually set the checksum to some random stuff, it won’t be updated